# Show label for value only when value exists, basic php

Tags: php, conditional-content

I currently have this,

```
<?php
$meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'rw_agentPhone', true);
echo "office:";
echo $meta; // if you want to show
?>
```

Which is fine provided there is a value for rw_agentPhone, but if the profile has no value entered it still displays office:, how can I rewrite this so that office: only dispalys if there is a value for rw_agentPhone.

I know this is basic php but I just haven't been able to crack this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **very** basic. Invest some time in a PHP tutorial. It’s fun! :)

Anyway …

```
<?php
$meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'rw_agentPhone', TRUE );
// get_post_meta() returns an empty string if it doesn’t find anything.
// We just test for this. If the string is not empty, we print it out.
'' != $meta and print "office: $meta";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was perfect, much simpler than what I was attempting. I had tried looking at some tutorials but I was thinking the solution would be an if/else but the solutions didn't seem appropriate, so I assumed I was going in the wrong direction.

Comment: @Chuck You could use `if ( '' != $meta ) { print '...'; }` but the one-liner is so much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a regular `if` structure:

```
if ($meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'rw_agentPhone', TRUE))
{
    echo 'office: ', $meta;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually really like the simplicity of toscho's first answer, I am just getting started with wordpress/php though so to see the various ways to go about is helpful.